# unique_ptr with custom pointer type: *get() and operator*() give different output

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) calling `std::unique_ptr::operator*()` is equivalent to calling `*(std::unique_ptr::get())`.

However I'm getting different results for both calls. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct file_descriptor
{
private:
  struct closer;

public:
  typedef int handle_type;
  typedef closer closer_type;

  constexpr static handle_type kInvalidHandle = -1;

public:
  file_descriptor(int handle = kInvalidHandle) : handle_{ handle } { }
  file_descriptor(std::nullptr_t) : file_descriptor{ } { }

  operator int&() { return handle_; }
  operator int() const { return handle_; }

  int& operator*() { return static_cast<int&>(*this); }
  int operator*() const { return static_cast<int>(*this); }

  bool operator==(const file_descriptor& other) const
  { return (handle_ == other.handle_); }

  bool operator!=(const file_descriptor& other) const
  { return !(*this == other); }

private:
  struct closer
  {
    typedef file_descriptor pointer;

    void operator()(pointer handle) const
    { ::close(*handle); }
  };

  int handle_;
};

using unique_file_ptr = std::unique_ptr<typename file_descriptor::handle_type,
                                        typename file_descriptor::closer_type>;

unique_file_ptr managed_open(const std::string& path)
{
  return { ::open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR), { } };
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  auto handle = managed_open("/dev/random");
  std::cout << "*handle      : " << *handle << std::endl;
  std::cout << "*handle.get(): " << *handle.get() << std::endl;
}
```

My output (live output [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58d7bf3a18197e1e)):

```
*handle      : 4198400
*handle.get(): 3
```

Please note that `*handle.get()` returns the correct value, while `*handle` doesn't.

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: @Lingxi No: `decltype(&::open) = int (*)(const char *, int, ...)`. I guess it's because `file_descriptor` is constructible from an `int`.

Comment: something funny happening because you've also overloaded `file_descriptor::operator*`? Try removing that and see what you get.

Comment: @RichardHodges Funnily enough, when I comment out the `operator*()'`s, the following error occurs: `.../include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:222:9: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('pointer' (aka 'file_descriptor') invalid)
        return *get();`, which means that `unique_ptr::operator*()` effectively is equivalent to `*get()`. This leads me to believe I'm somehow invoking UB in my code.

Comment: The `return static_cast<int&>(*this);` line looks really smelly. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: `unique_file_ptr::element_type` is `file_descriptor::handle_type`, while `unique_file_ptr::pointer` is `file_descriptor`. I'm just double-bent ~>_<~

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. It would make sense to store the result of `fopen` in a unique_ptr with a custom deleter that closes the file stream. But `open` returns an integer, not a pointer. You can't just pretend that the integer is really a class.

Comment: @milleniumbug it calls `file_descriptor::operator int&()`.

Comment: @RichardHodges The result from `open` will automatically be converted to a `pointer` (aka file_descriptor) before being passed to unique_ptr's constructor (because unique_ptr's constructor takes a _pointer_ by value). The unique_ptr doesn't store an int, it stores a file_descriptor.

Comment: The fix would appear to be simply removing `operator int&()` from `file_descriptor`. Is there any particular reason you need a reference in addition to the `operator int()` overload? It seems dangerous to expose a modifiable reference - client code could change the managed descriptor and the old value would leak instead of being properly destroyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what happens. `unique_ptr<T, D>::get()` returns `D::pointer` - in your case, a temporary `file_descriptor` constructed from the `int` handle. Then its `operator*` calls its `operator int&` which returns a reference to `handle_` stored inside that temporary.

When you call `*handle.get()` directly, the `int&` reference it produces is used before the temporary dies.

But when you call `*handle` instead, you call `handle.operator*()` which in turn calls `handle.get()`. The implementation of `operator*`, with everything expanded, becomes something like this:

```
int& operator*() {
  file_descriptor temp(internal_pointer_);
  int& result = temp.handle_;
  return result;
}
```

The function returns a reference to the member of a temporary. That temporary dies at the closing brace, and the reference becomes dangling, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior triggered by accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: So `unique_ptr::pointer` should better be a real pointer type :p

Comment: I came to the same conclusion while sifting through the code for unique_ptr in my stdlib. And while some may argue the usability of my code, I was just playing around with unique_ptr since it seemed like an easy way to get some RAI behaviour. I'm just gonna try to find a way to make this work with unique_ptr (for _educational_ purposes).

Comment: @Lingxi Not necessarily. It's OK for it to be a proxy class - but the proxy object shouldn't be making a copy of the object being proxied. Having said that, in this particular example `file_descriptor` doesn't appear to serve any useful purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Indeed. In the questionable code, `unique_ptr::pointer` is the real entity type `file_descriptor` with no indirection.

Comment: @TomKnapen I think the obscure relationship between `unique_file_ptr::element_type` and `unique_file_ptr::pointer` is what breaks the original code.

Comment: The problem just reminds me of `std::vector<bool>`. Way too technical :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you re-think the solution. Here's an arguably cleaner way to approach it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct managed_file {
    managed_file() noexcept {};
    managed_file(const std::string& path) 
    : _handle { ::open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR) }
    {
        if (_handle == -1) {
            throw std::runtime_error { std::string { "failed to open file " } + path };
        }
    }

    managed_file(const managed_file&) = delete;
    managed_file(managed_file&& other) noexcept 
    : _handle { other._handle }
    {
        other._handle = -1;
    }

    managed_file& operator=(const managed_file&) = delete;
    managed_file& operator=(managed_file&& other) noexcept {
        managed_file tmp { std::move(other) };
        using std::swap;
        swap(_handle, other._handle);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~managed_file() noexcept 
    {
        close();
    }

    void close() noexcept {
        if (_handle != -1) {
            ::close(_handle);
            _handle = -1;
        }
    }

    const int& operator*() const noexcept {
        return _handle;
    }

private:
    int _handle = -1;
};

managed_file managed_open(const std::string& path)
{
    return managed_file { path };
}

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{

    cout << "opening" << endl;
    auto handle = managed_open("/dev/random");

    cout << "checking" << endl;
    std::cout << "*handle      : " << *handle << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I guess the OP is trying to reuse `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Of course I understand that - but it's not a natural fit the way he's trying to do it.